Equivalence Condition between Eigenvalues and Semi-Positive Definite Matrices
I am trying to understand why : For a semi-positive definite matrix $A$, the condition that all eigenvalues are non-negative is equivalent to $x^{T}Ax≥0$ for all $x$.
Here is my attempt to work through the math.
A semi-positive definite matrix is a symmetric matrix that has non-negative eigenvalues.
A symmetric $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is positive semi-definite if for all vectors $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$:
$$x^T A x \geq 0$$
To determine if a matrix is semi-positive definite, one way to do so is to calculate the eigenvalues of the matrix. If all eigenvalues are non-negative (≥ 0), the matrix is semi-positive definite.
Using the properties of matrices, for a symmetric matrix $A$, we can find an orthogonal matrix Q such that:
$$A = Q\Lambda Q^T$$
where:

$\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues of A
the columns of Q are the corresponding eigenvectors.

Next, consider the quadratic form $x^TAx$:
$$x^TAx = x^T(Q\Lambda Q^T)x$$
Define $y = Q^Tx$.
Since Q is orthogonal, $Q^T = Q^{-1}$, so $x = Qy$.
Substituting this:
$$x^TAx = (Qy)^T(Q\Lambda Q^T)(Qy) = y^TQ^TQ\Lambda Q^TQy = y^T\Lambda y$$
Since $\Lambda$ is diagonal, this simplifies to (i.e. matrix multiplication is a sum):
$$y^T\Lambda y = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i y_i^2$$
where:

$\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of A
$y_i$ are the components of y.

And this is where the logic is invoked:

We know that $y_i{^2}$ is always positive since its squared.
Since we are assuming the matrix $A$ has non-negative eigenvalues, all $\lambda_i$ are also positive.
We just showed that $x^T A x$ = $y^T\Lambda y$
Finally, all this means that if some matrix $A$ has only positive eigenvalues, we can
"sandwich" (i.e. multiply) this matrix between any two vectors $x$ and $x^T$, and the resulting product will always be positive

Is my work correct?

You are missing the other direction, if $0\leq x^T A x$ for all $x$, then if $x$ is an eigen vector with eigen value $\lambda$, you get $0\leq x^T A x = \lambda x^2$ and therefore as $x\neq 0$, $0\leq \lambda$.
